# I have a record in mongoDB like below. Need a query to get the previous day results using startTime

Tags: mongodb

I have a record in mongoDB like below. Need a query to get the previous day results using startTime.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5c08d195d38e4040788c789a"),
    "jobName": "test-ci-build",
    "build": "474",
    "buildURL": "https://example.com/test-ci-build/474/",
    "result": "SUCCESS",
    "startTime": "2018-12-06T05:42:22+0000",
    "duration": "1 hr 54 min",
    "startTimeInMillis": 1544074942061,
    "triggeredBy": "Started by timer",
    "commit": "b8a04837f1c285e6d9d8852af5801419acd047cb",
    "date": ISODate("2018-12-06T07:36:53.045Z")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [$lt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) or [$lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) MongoDB operators on the startTime field, you may get the required data.

You can use:

```
db.collection.find({startTime:{$lte: "2018-12-06T05:42:22+0000"}})
```

or

```
db.collection.find({startTime:{$lte: ISODate("2018-12-06T05:42:22+0000")}})
```

Consider to find the result for your "startDate < TodaysDate - 1" expression we will compare your "date" field with todays date. (You can modify the Mongo query as per your date fields).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      yesterdays_date: {
        $subtract: [
          new Date().getTime(),
          86400000
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      convertedDate: {
        $toDate: "$yesterdays_date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "dateComp": {
        "$cmp": [
          "$date",
          "$convertedDate"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "dateComp": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      yesterdays_date: 0,
      convertedDate: 0,
      dateComp: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Hi Kulkarni, Thanks for your quick turn up. Its working fine. But i need to pass the date as system date like startDate < TodaysDate - 1

Comment: To calculate the date of day before the current date you need to minus the 1 day timestamp (1000*60*60*24=86400000) from the current date like: 

day before the current date = current date - 86400000;

Comment: I have updated the Mongo query in my last answer as per "startDate < TodaysDate - 1". Please check once is it full filling your requirement or not.